# How to access the search LookupFields result

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Below is my search code. I'm searching for the Invoice number by using the invoice internal ID.

What is the right way to access the lookupFields search result?

```
var invoiceNumber = fieldLookUp.value;
```

I'm using the above line but the "**invoiceNumber**" is empty. Thanks for your help.

```
var fieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
                    type: search.Type.INVOICE,
                    id: invoiceId,
                    columns: 'tranid'
                });

                var invoiceNumber = fieldLookUp.value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would just be `fieldLookUp.tranid`. `lookupFields` returns an Object where the Object's keys are your Columns and the Object's values are the Column values.

Check out this video for more details on Field Lookups in SS2.0: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fs2thUdEmQ

Comment: For me this returns org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray@3ae2d1c2

Comment: That's correct. A Lookup on any type of Select field returns an Array. Stringify the return value in your logs so you can see its structure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the value

```
fieldLookUp[0].value
```

or vice versa, if you want to get the text data

```
fieldLookUp[0].text
```